# VLOOKUP cells that contain a certain text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

The challenge is as follows: I have a column with names extracted from a source. The names come in different ways each time it is extracted. For me to be able to use it, I need the names in a specific way.

For example:

Names extracted from source:

**Column A**

- Julieta Venega Caceres
- Jose Manuel Pinzon
- Carmen Monica de Roux
- Jose Ponce

Names in the format I need:

**Column B**

- Julieta Venega Caceres Gonzalez
- Jose Manuel Pinzon Espinosa
- Carmen Monica Solis de Roux
- Jose Antonio Ponce

Temporarily solution:

> =VLOOKUP(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)&"*",B:B,1,0)
>   I'm looking for the first name in column A and then match it with the names of column B.

The problem is that some names start with the same first name, ex. there are two names that starts with Jose. In this case the function would not be accurate for all names.

Comment: Does it have to be a formula? In vba you could use INSTR to look for the partial name as a pattern in the other column. You didn't explain what you hope to do when a match is found

Comment: So you have a master list of names correctly formatted.  New names come in.  Will the new names always be for people contained in the master list?  Will the first name always be in the same form, or could you need to deal with nicknames, abbreviated names, misspellings, or other differences?  Is the only problem occasional duplicate first names?  Have you looked at a double lookup (match first name plus find second name in the same master record)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for this. It will read in two tables and return a table with the best match (or matches), along with confidence and similarity scores.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

You would need to prepare your data by separating your 2 columns into 2 tables.